# Laravel 5.4 password reset using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/password/email", 
    data: {
        _token: $(".modal-forgotpass-content input[name='_token']").val(),
        email: $(".modal-forgotpass-content input[name='email']").val()
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Successful : link send");
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("Faild: link not send");
    }
});
```

Controller (this function comes with Laravel 5.4) :

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink($request->only('email'));

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
        : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

Routes :

```
Auth::routes();
```

This code works well, but it sends the password reset link to all emails even if the email does not exist in database (users table). I want the link to be sent only to the emails that already exist in the user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using validate like

```
$this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);
```

Validate it like below

```
$this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email|exists:users']);
```

This should validate if user email exists in database or not.

Comment: @IlhamGuezzoula If your the email is not in the column called "id" you need `exists:users,<emailColumn>`

Comment: On my end it is showing 
message Method [getBroker] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController].
exception BadMethodCallException